# How can I make the Next.js "dev" server safe for production?

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, hybrid

My team's primary goal is to be able to "snapshot" a CMS-driven site to static HTML. This is straightforward [using `getStaticProps` and `next export`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export#how-to-use-it).

But we also need to host an intranet version always fetching latest content from the CMS. Using `getStaticProps` this is not really possible because its output is cached, and if you use the older `getInitialProps` you can't "freeze" the server version of its output during export.

`next dev` makes this easy; it has a service that offers up fresh versions of the JSON files that will be made static during export.

On a long-running site, are there important configuration changes that would make `next dev` safe/safer to use?

Answer (score 0):

In 9.5 Next added [Incremental Static Regeneration](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#incremental-static-regeneration), a fancy way of saying `getStaticProps` will regularly invalidate its output some time after the next time it's requested.

This is still not ideal because someone who makes a CMS edit will want to see the change reflected on the very next request, but instead they'll see the old content, wait a few seconds, and reload the page.

On static export, nothing changes: `getStaticProps` turns into a static JSON file.